# Trouble shortening my MediaWiki site URL? Where is <directory> directive?

Tags: apache, mediawiki

I am using a basic hosting plan on Host Gator. I installed MediaWiki and I am getting URLs with `index.php?title=` in it, i.e. `www.domain.com/index.php?title=Main_Page`

I want to remove the `index.php?title=` part and just have the title of the page appear. I am following the instructions from http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Page_title_--_Windows_%26_Apache_without_403_on_Special_Pages, not sure if this is the right instructions I should be using.

Step 1 of the instructions indicate that "If you have vHosts configured, insert the following Rewrite directives into the appropriate `<VirtualHost>` directive. Otherwise, insert it in the `<directory>` directive for your wiki's root directory:" and to insert:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^/(.*):(.*) /index.php/$1:$2
```

Where is the `<directory>` directive located? What file should I be inserting the code into?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`<directory>` block](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) is a httpd.conf Apache configuration file directive.

On a shared hosting enviroment, you don't generally have directly access to his file. You still have access to an [.htaccess file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html), which allows most configuration directives to be used.

Create a .htaccess at your web root (the same directory you have `index.php` and `LocalSettings.php`) and write the RewriteEngine / RewriteRules directives in this file.

If this fails, follow instead this guide, more adapted to your situation: 
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache